# AMPL: How can I run a for loop in AMPL to perform a logical comparison?

Tags: for-loop, ampl

#### variables:

```
    set I:={1..4}; # prod 1-4
    var x{I} >=0 integer; # Set this to a non-negative number!
    var y{I} binary;  # Fixed cost is no matter what!
```

Constraints:
#Profit
#**I have tried this and it does work:**
**however I want to make it cleaner with less duplicate code.**

```
    #s.t. p1: x[1] <= y[1]*Profit[1];
    #s.t. p2: x[2] <= y[2]*Profit[2];
    #s.t. p3: x[3] <= y[3]*Profit[3]; 
    #s.t. p4: x[4] <= y[4]*Profit[4];
```

not pretty but it works.
I want to iterate through the list  {i in I} to make it cleaner.

**I have tried These and they do not work.**

```
    s.t. pRofit: for{i in I}{ x[i]} <= for{i in I}{ y[i] * Profit[i]};
    s.t. pRofit: sum{i in I}{ x[i]} <= sum{i in I}{ y[i] * Profit[i]};
```

Does AMPL offer a for loop solution?

**I have tried These and they do not work.**`

```
    s.t. pRofit: for{i in I}{ x[i]} <= for{i in I}{ y[i] * Profit[i]};
    s.t. pRofit: sum{i in I}{ x[i]} <= sum{i in I}{ y[i] * Profit[i]};

    * even tried the suggested stackO solutions:
    s.t. c1{i in S}: x[i] = y[i]*Profit[i]; by: GB supports the mod strike.
```

Does AMPL offer a for loop solution?

Answer (score 1):

So I posted the question and forgot, using cplex;

also went back and tried it again and boom this worked.

```
 s.t. pRofit{i in I}: x[i] <=  y[i] * Profit[i];
```